# "JQMIGRATE" error when visiting an https site with capybara and poltergeist in ruby program

Tags: ruby, capybara, poltergeist

I have a program

It was running fine about a year and a half ago when I last ran it, but running it now I get an error.

I have made a small program that demonstrates the error.

The program is-

```
 require 'capybara/poltergeist'
 session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)


print "visiting http://www.wikipedia.com \r\n"                                                                                                    


session.visit('http://www.wikipedia.com')

print "no error visiting http://www.wikipedia.com \r\n"                                                                                                    

print "visiting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup \r\n"                                                                                                    

session.visit('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup')

print "blah"  # prints blah so gets that far even though error from previous line.
```

Before running the program i've set the path  `@PATH=%PATH%;c:\gecko;c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox;c:\phantomjs\bin`

The path was always and is still fine.e.g. the first session.visit line (the one to http rather than https) works

```
C:\rubytest\wikipediathing\current>ruby wikipediatest2.rb
visiting http://www.wikipedia.com
no error visiting http://www.wikipedia.com
visiting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 3.0.1
This page is using the deprecated ResourceLoader module "schema.UniversalLanguageSelector".
See https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T205744 for migration info.
blah
C:\rubytest\wikipediathing\current>
```

I went to https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T205744  but it just talks about event logging so I don't see the applicability or any solution at that link.

Comment: I guess perhaps the fact that print "blah" at the end runs indicates that it was a warning rather than an error 'cos perhaps an error would've stopped the program completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not technically seeing an error there, you're seeing JS console log output from some of the libraries used on the page.  Whether or not they are errors or just warnings is unclear from what you've shown, but it could very well be that wikipedia has upgraded the libraries used on the page to versions that no longer support the version of PhantomJS being used by Poltergeist. This can happen because PhantomJS development was stopped/abandoned due to QtWebKit no longer being developed. That has left Poltegeist/PhantomJS basically equivalent to a 6-7 year old version of Safari which is getting beyond the age where any website owner/developer really cares about supporting. Long term You're going to be much better off upgrading your program to using headless chrome via the selenium driver rather than the poltergeist driver.

Comment: what more is required to determine whether it's an error or a warning?   have a more developed program that doesn't work though it used to work

Comment: @barlop you’d have to find where the logging statements are being called from and what the actual meaning of them is - However since youre app isn’t working it’s likely that wikipedia is no longer compatible with PhantomJS. You can upgrade to the latest (2.1.1) version if you’re not already using that, but the real solution is moving to headless chrome

Comment: ah, the program mentioned in my comment was a red herring.. It may be you're right that the sample in the question only involves warnings not errors.

Comment: you're right it was just a warning. I found some other code that did `require 'capybara/poltergeist'` and `session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)` and  `session.visit('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFA_World_Cup')` and `session.fill_in('search', :with => 'zzz')` and `session.save_screenshot('aaa.png')` 
`
`